# How can I enter commands in Minecraft server that was run remotely using PowerShell invoke-command on local computer?

Tags: powershell, remote-access, minecraft

I am running a Minecraft server from my laptop since it has an i7 and more RAM than my desktop. I want to be able to see the server command line on my desktop and be able to enter commands while the server is actually running on my laptop. I was able to see the command line by setting up for remote access and running the command

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName 10.0.0.53 -Credential Admin -ScriptBlock { & "RUNSERVER.bat"}
```

This made it so I am able to see what the server is outputting to the PowerShell window on my desktop and the server is running on the laptop like it should be, but I am still unable to enter any commands. I'm pretty inexperienced with PowerShell so I'm not too sure where to go from here. Anyone out there know how I can edit this so that I can input commands from the PowerShell window on my desktop?

```
[localhost] Connecting to remote server localhost failed with the following error message : WinRM cannot process the request. The following error with
errorcode 0x8009030d occurred while using Negotiate authentication: A specified logon session does not exist. It may already have been terminated.
 Possible causes are:
  -The user name or password specified are invalid.
  -Kerberos is used when no authentication method and no user name are specified.
  -Kerberos accepts domain user names, but not local user names.
  -The Service Principal Name (SPN) for the remote computer name and port does not exist.
  -The client and remote computers are in different domains and there is no trust between the two domains.
 After checking for the above issues, try the following:
  -Check the Event Viewer for events related to authentication.
  -Change the authentication method; add the destination computer to the WinRM TrustedHosts configuration setting or use HTTPS transport.
 Note that computers in the TrustedHosts list might not be authenticated.
   -For more information about WinRM configuration, run the following command: winrm help config. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting
Help topic.
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (localhost:String) [], PSRemotingTransportException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : 1312,PSSessionStateBroken
```

```
[localhost] Connecting to remote server localhost failed with the following error message : The WinRM client cannot process the request. CredSSP authentication
is currently disabled in the client configuration. Change the client configuration and try the request again. CredSSP authentication must also be enabled in
the server configuration. Also, Group Policy must be edited to allow credential delegation to the target computer. Use gpedit.msc and look at the following
policy: Computer Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> System -> Credentials Delegation -> Allow Delegating Fresh Credentials.  Verify that it is
enabled and configured with an SPN appropriate for the target computer. For example, for a target computer name "myserver.domain.com", the SPN can be one of
the following: WSMAN/myserver.domain.com or WSMAN/*.domain.com For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (localhost:String) [], PSRemotingTransportException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : -2144108126,PSSessionStateBroken
```

```
2019-04-19 20:00:08,630 main WARN Unable to instantiate org.fusesource.jansi.WindowsAnsiOutputStream
2019-04-19 20:00:08,631 main WARN Unable to instantiate org.fusesource.jansi.WindowsAnsiOutputStream
```

Answer (score 2):

Enter-PSSession -Computername "Laptop"

You are now in a remote powershell session on the machine you identified via the computer name parameter.

Some things to be aware of. If you're doing this in a workgroup and not a domain you're going to need to contend with passing credentials. You have to pass them as a credentials object in PS. So it looks a bit more like this:

```
$Creds = Get-Credential
enter-pssession -ComputerName 10.0.0.53 -Credential $Creds
```

for credentials enter a username and PW that exists on the remote machine.

The Firewall on the remote host also needs to be configured to allow inbound Windows Remote Management Framework traffic from your local host.

Comment: For some reason, this achieves the same results. I am running the PowerShell script used to start the server once I'm in the remote session but I still cannot enter anything into the PowerShell window after the server has started. If I run the same script from my laptop the server starts and I am able to enter commands like normal. Is there some sort of parameter I need to enter to be able to do this from the remote window?

Comment: I see you are trying to run a script/ batch file on the remote server. Is the script you're calling located on the server or the client? When you use Invoke-command think of it as running the exact text block on the server as if you were in a powershell session on the server. So if you're calling to a .bat file that does not exist on the server than it will not run anything. In that case copy the .bat file to the server and specify the full path in your scriptblock parameter.

Answer (score 0):

EDITED THE ORIGINAL ANSWER TO REFLECT MY LATEST ANSWER:

This is where Windows will fall short on these kind of things. Windows by default does not have Pseudoterminal (PTY) support.

Traditionally, in *NIX type systems, you can run ssh -t option to access screen mode (forces TTY).

You might have better luck using this powershell module and following their instructions here: https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/wiki/TTY-PTY-support-in-Windows-OpenSSH

Comment: I was able to run the server like this, but I didn't see any way to give it any input, although I was able to see what had been outputted to the console using receive-job.

Comment: @Idunnowhy You would need to use Zack A's answer to give it additional input (```Enter-PSSession -ComputerName 10.0.0.53 -Credential (Get-Credential)```). The Invoke-Command is only ran once. You can run the same code in the script block once you're in the session using ```Invoke-Command -ComputerName localhost -Credential Admin -ScriptBlock { & "RUNSERVER.bat"} -AsJob``` using localhost as the computer name.

Comment: When I do this it returns that the job is running, but if I type get-job the state is listed as failed

Comment: @Idunnowhy seems like your winrm is not configured on your localhost. You can do this by running ```winrm /quickconfig``` and following the prompts

Comment: Run the Invoke-Command command without the asjob switch and let it fail (as you confirmed the job is failing) and paste the error output to let me see what is failing :)

Comment: I added the error the bottom of the main post, thank you for helping me out.

Comment: @Idunnowhy no problem, I enjoy helping out any way I can!

That said, are you in a PSSession at the Minecraft server when running the invoke-command?

Comment: Yes, I am in the directory where the .bat files is

Comment: Try specifying the authentication method for the invoke-command. I'm not sure if it's causing the old "double-hop" issue found in PSRemoting. ```Invoke-Command -ComputerName localhost -Credential Admin -ScriptBlock { & "RUNSERVER.bat"} -Authentication CredSSP```

Comment: Hmm that is giving me another error, posted that up under the other one

Comment: It might be just easier to just run the batch job as a process than going through troubleshooting PSRemoting issues. Try Start-Process “RUNSERVER.bat”

Comment: That seemed to work, however, I still need to find a way to be able to input stuff into the console

Comment: Are you referring to the console of the Minecraft server started from “RUNSERVER.bat” or the console of the actual laptop? Those are two different things.

Comment: The console from the batch file is what I mean, when I start it from the laptop I can input console command just fine, but when I start it as a process I can't see where I am supposed to input anything. If I execute the batch file normally while I'm in the PSSession I can see the console output but I can't type anything.

Comment: I’m not sure how Minecraft servers are run... quick google search leaves me to believe it’s in Java. (Correct me if I’m wrong) If it’s Java, you can run the Minecraft server jar file using the “java -jar pathTOjarFILE.jar nogui”. You should be able to send commands afterwards. I would try to look for the line in your batch file where it calls the jar file and add the nogui argument.

Comment: I tried this earlier but it just doesn't let me type anything in afterwards for some reason if I am using the remote session. Running the jar from PowerShell on my laptop works normally. When it runs the remote session it also produces a unique error while starting the server, I'll post it above if you have got any clue as to what that could be.

Comment: This is where Windows will fall short on these kind of things. Windows by default does not have Pseudoterminal (PTY) support. Traditionally, in *NIX type systems, you can run ssh -t option to access screen mode (forces TTY). You might have better luck using this powershell module and following their instructions here: https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/wiki/TTY-PTY-support-in-Windows-OpenSSH

Comment: OpenSSH did the trick! I was able to do exactly what I wanted. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Glad we worked through it! Have fun in Minecraft :)